# Access side input in a non - anonymous DoFn

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

How to access the elements of a side input if I have my class extend DoFn?

For example:

Say I have a ParDo transform like:

```java
PCollection<String> data = myData.apply("Get data",
    ParDo.of(new MyClass()).withSideInputs(myDataView));
```

And I have a class:-

```java
static class MyClass extends DoFn<String,String>
{
    //How to access side input here
}
```

c.sideInput() isn't working in this case.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you please show what error you are getting? This section shows an example that should work. Can you please try this by using an anymous class as shown in the example, then once that works try replacing it with your class. Both have the same base class, so I think it should work, unless there is some issue overriding something.

https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/model/par-do#passing-side-inputs-to-pardo

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In this case, the problem is that the `processElement` method in your DoFn does not have access to the PCollectionView instance in your main method.

You can pass the PCollectionView to the DoFn in the constructor:

```java
class MyClass extends DoFn<String,String>
{
    private final PCollectionView<..> mySideInput;

    public MyClass(PCollectionView<..> mySideInput) {
        // List, or Map or anything:
        this.mySideInput = mySideInput;
    }

    @ProcessElement
    public void processElement(ProcessContext c) throws IOException
    {
        // List or Map or any type you need:
        List<..> sideInputList = c.sideInput(mySideInput);
    }
}
```

You would then pass the side input to the class when you instantiate it, and indicate it as a side input like so:

```java
p.apply(ParDo.of(new MyClass(mySideInput)).withSideInputs(mySideInput));
```

---

The explanation for this is that when you use an anonymous DoFn, the process method has a closure with access to all the objects within the scope that encloses the DoFn (among them is the PCollectionView). When you're not using an anonymous DoFn, there is no closure, and you need another way of passing the PCollectionView.

Answer (score 3):

So although the answer above is correct, it is still a little incomplete.

So once you finish implementing the above answer, you need to execute your pipeline like this:

```
    p.apply(ParDo.of(new MyClass(mySideInput)).withSideInputs(mySideInput));
```